# Fog Of War for Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I've been experimenting a fog of war. I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNAvNeOTnSE) apparently this is unity 4 and I'm using unity 5, I'm currently getting this error:

> Surface shader vertex function 'vert' not found

I read on the comment section on this youtube video, I followed them, but it gives me the error. Tried the original version(The one in the video) but it makes my plane a always underneath even though it's y axis is zero, and the main map's y axis is -10.

btw here is my code for my shader:

```
Shader "Custom/FogOWarShader" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "LightMode"="ForwardBase" }
    Blend SrcAlpha  OneMinusSrcAlpha
    Lighting Off
    LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM

    //#pragma surface surf NoLighting Lambert alpha:blend --the one that makes the map always on top
    #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert alpha:blend

    fixed4 LightingNoLighting(SurfaceOutput s, fixed3 lightDir, float aten){

        fixed4 color;
        color.rgb = s.Albedo;
        color.a = s.Alpha;
        return color;

    }

    fixed4 _Color;
    sampler2D _MainTex;

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
    };


    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {

        half4 baseColor = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
        o.Albedo = _Color.rgb * baseColor.b;
        o.Alpha = _Color.a - baseColor.g;
        }
        ENDCG
    } 
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a line in that shader which says:

```
#pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert alpha:blend
```

So you say you have a vertex shader called `vert`, but then there is no such function in the rest of your code. That is what it's complaining about.

Having taken a look at the actual shader, all you need to do it set up the blending. You can do that by modifying the `pragma` that is in the original shader to

```
#pragma surface surf NoLighting noambient alpha:blend
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Okay thanks. Apparently I don't have any clue on how to use shader. Any idea to solve this problem?